# Relation between tensile strength of a material and potential energy stored within the material

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If I were to stretch a highly inelastic material up to a distance x, what would be the energy stored in it? What other factors would I have to incorporate to measure the potential energy if the information given above isn't satisfactory?

Comment: If you know the constitutive law of the material, it should be quite easy to recognize conservative (related to internal potential energy) and non conservative contributions. If you have it, could you provide it?

Comment: If you're free, can you please explain what is 'constitutive law' of a material? I haven't studied this yet. I thought of launching spacecraft into space using the internal potential energy of stretching a material for a project, thus the doubt.

Comment: Can you define exactly what you mean by “highly inelastic”? There are several ways the elasticity idealization can be violated. Please clarify how the material is behaving, e.g., by a stress–strain diagram.

Answer (score 0):

We first imagine the "highly inelastic" material to be *stiff*.

It is then a *spring* and will assume to first order that it is linear.

We make a plot of the force with which the spring resists the stretching on the y axis versus the amount of stretch on the x axis. We measure the *slope* of that plot, which is the stiffness constant k.

The stored energy in the spring is the integral of the force over the distance x, which is equal to the area under that curve in our plot. For a linear spring with stiffness constant k, this is equal to 1/2(kx^2).

Comment: How do I measure the spring constant k only with ultimate tensile strength (assume room temperature)

Comment: I will edit. -NN